# How to use regex for redirects of dynamic routes in next.config.js(or vercel)? Where's the source code of redirects?

Tags: regex, redirect, next.js, vercel

I have a next.js(v13) project and in next.config.js, it looks like:

```
async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/:user',
                destination: '/:user/food/apple',
                permanent: true
            }
        ]
    }
```

but it would also redirects /404 or even /favicon.ico, which I definitely do not want. Then how to exclude them in the next.config.js?

I searched a lot and read the docs. I tried with /:user((?!404)) or /:user(?!404) or /:user(^!404) or sort of things but none of them works. It would also be helpful if someone show me the link of the source code related to that exact config thing.